# Child divs not starting at the top of the parent for small height values

Tags: css

I want to make sort of a timeline. By doing so, I have a `div` with `class="parent"` which has child divs with their width relative to the number of divisions on the timeline.

The problem is that for smaller `height` values in the parent div, the child divs don't get drawn where expected.

I made a simple example in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q7xs4g9f/3/

```js
let parent = document.getElementsByClassName("parent")[0];

let nrDivisions = 10;
for(let i = 0; i < nrDivisions; i++) {
  let division = document.createElement("div");
  division.classList.add("division");
  division.style.width = 100 / nrDivisions + "%";
  parent.appendChild(division);
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
    height: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(97, 186, 255);
    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.division {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid thin #444;
  border-right: none;
  background-color: rgb(255, 186, 186);
  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent div:last-child.division {
  border-right: solid thin #444;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"></div>
```

I've set the parent's `height: 5px` and it won't work (you can also try with 10px, for example). However, by setting the value to something bigger (say 20px), it works as expected.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to the inline-blocks.

https://jsfiddle.net/r1guh28c/1/

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But shouldn't this be the default behaviour?

Comment: no, the default setting is `baseline`, since they are inline elements